# 500 Internal Error appears after adding the codes in .htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, perl, .htaccess

The issue is:

I have a WordPress site running on 4.3 and using the theme from Envato Market (POND v2.0). And I ran an SEO test using this website ([SEO Checkup Test](http://seositecheckup.com)). After going through the tips on how to improve the SEO score, I followed the advice of fixing the IP Canonical Test by adding this code in the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^XXX\.XXX\.XXX\.XXX
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, I cannot find the file in my DirectAdmin and Googled on how to open it. I managed to open it but the file shows nothing. Then I looked for the default rules which is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(dev|failed_auth.html)/?.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
</IfModule>
```

After adding these functions and saving it, my WordPress site shows the 500 Internal error. When I removed it, the website is back to normal. What is the possible issue behind these weird problem? I need to add the IP Canonical to the file. Not only the IP Canonical, there is the Perl. WWW code too.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to httpd.conf the search this line

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

take the hash out

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

restart apatche